# reading large .gdb file with geopandas

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapefile

I am trying to read a large (350k polygons) .gdb file into python as follows:

```
mydata = gpd.read_file(r'Key_Layers.gdb',layer='Hazard')
```

However, it is only reading ~50k out of ~350k polygons. And it also takes about 12 hours to complete.

I have also tried to read a single row at a time, e.g.

```
mydata = gpd.read_file(r'Key_Layers.gdb',layer='Hazard',rows=1)
```

But this doesn't appear to be working either - instead it just loads the whole dataset.

EDIT:
I have now also tried fiona but am still having problems reading the file (it hangs/takes a very long time to do anything):

```
with fiona.open(filename,layer='Hazard') as source:
for i in source:
        print(i)
```

Note: There are multiple layers in this file, and it is only the layer called "Hazard" that I have a problem with. The other layers import fine with the above fiona code looping through each item. Could it be that the 'Hazard' layer is too large?

Comment: From the source code, `gpd.read_file()` returns everthing parsed in an object. This approach requires a lot of memory and may run out of memory. If your application needs to read large amount of data, i suggest you extend the function to store parsed data progressively into a database or file, which could be access when the function has returned. This put a far smaller memory stress on the operating system.